# Referencing TableStreamArn in Amazon CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I have the following configuration:

```
    //DynamoDB Table
    const table = new dynamodb.Table(this, `DataStore`, {
      tableName: `${StackConfiguration.appName}-data-${StackConfiguration.environmentKey}`,
      partitionKey: { name: 'scope', type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING },
      sortKey: { name: 'id', type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING },
      readCapacity: 5,
      writeCapacity: 5,
      removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
      stream: StreamViewType.NEW_IMAGE
      
    });

    // Define Call Scaler Lambda
    const callScalerLambda = new lambda.Function(this, 'CallLambdaHandler', {
      description: 'Call Scaler Document Aggregate Lambda',
      functionName: `${StackConfiguration.appName}-call-scaler-${StackConfiguration.environmentKey}`,
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8, // execution environment
      handler: 'call-scaler/call_lambda.lambda_handler', // file is myLambda, function is lambda_handler
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('lambda'), // code loaded from the "lambda" directory
      role: myIAMRole,
      environment: {
        ENVIRONMENT: StackConfiguration.environmentKey,
        SCALERENV: StackConfiguration.scalerEnvironment,
        SYSTEMUSERNAME: StackConfiguration.systemUserName,
        SYSTEMUSERPASS: StackConfiguration.systemUserPass
        
      },
    });

    const DocumentAggregateCallScalerEventTrigger = new lambda.EventSourceMapping(this, 'DocumentEventTrigger', {
      target:callScalerLambda,
    
      // the properties below are optional
      batchSize: 1,
      enabled: true,
      eventSourceArn: table.tableStreamArn,
      startingPosition: lambda.StartingPosition.LATEST
    });
```

I am trying to simply define an EventSourceTrigger via the `DocumentAggregateCallScalerEventTrigger` and define the `eventSourceArn` as the table's streamArn. However, I continue to get the following errors:

```
error   13-Dec-2021 15:23:39    FAIL test/stack.test.ts
error   13-Dec-2021 15:23:39      ● Test suite failed to run
error   13-Dec-2021 15:23:39    
error   13-Dec-2021 15:23:39        [96mlib/stack.ts[0m:[93m206[0m:[93m7[0m - [91merror[0m[90m TS2322: [0mType 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
error   13-Dec-2021 15:23:39          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
error   13-Dec-2021 15:23:39    
error   13-Dec-2021 15:23:39        [7m206[0m       eventSourceArn: table.tableStreamArn,
error   13-Dec-2021 15:23:39        [7m   [0m [91m      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[0m
error   13-Dec-2021 15:23:39    
error   13-Dec-2021 15:23:39          [96mnode_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-lambda/lib/event-source-mapping.d.ts[0m:[93m9[0m:[93m14[0m
error   13-Dec-2021 15:23:39            [7m9[0m     readonly eventSourceArn: string;
error   13-Dec-2021 15:23:39            [7m [0m [96m             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[0m
error   13-Dec-2021 15:23:39            The expected type comes from property 'eventSourceArn' which is declared here on type 'EventSourceMappingProps'
```

**How do I properly reference the table's StreamArn in the CDK?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as Typescript is concerned, `table.tableStreamArn` is an optional string (`string | undefined`), so it's not letting you assign it to a required `eventSourceArn` prop. In reality, `table.tableStreamArn` will resolve to a string, because you have set the `stream` prop on your table.  But Typescript has no way of figuring this out on its own.

There are various ways to make Typescript happy, some more elegant than others: You can assert non-null with `table.tableStreamArn!`, for instance, or force to a string `table?.tableStreamArn ?? 'SHOULD NOT HAPPEN'`. Or
throw an error if it is undefined.

Another option would be add the event source right on the lambda, which avoids the whole issue:

```js
import * as evtsrc from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-event-sources';

callScalerLambda.addEventSource(
  new evtsrc.DynamoEventSource(table, {
    batchSize: 1,
    enabled: true,
    startingPosition: lambda.StartingPosition.LATEST,
  })
);
```